# Microsoft Word: Repeating a figure without renumbering

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I'm writing a paper for a scientific journal and need to repeat all of my figures at the end of the document for the editor's perusal. My figures are dynamically numbered, and the figures at the end must have the *same* numbers as those earlier in the document. Copy-pasting the figures to the end of the document gives them new numbers.

Is there a way of doing this without having to manually adjust the numbers? Maybe some way of inserting a figure as a direct duplicate of one earlier in the document?

Comment: Are the figures going to be repeated in exactly the same sequence at the end as in the main text? If so, and the figures do not use chapter-sequence numbering (i.e. they are 1, 2, 3, not "1-1, 1-2, 2-1"), all you really need do is reset the relevant SEQ field between at the start of the copied figures. e.g. your figures will be numbered via { SEQ Figure \* Arabic }. Before the "figures at the end", insert { SEQ Figure \*Arabic \r 0 }. If you use chapter-sequence numbering, that won't be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

- Save your document, and make a copy of it.
- Open the copy.
- Select all the material and press ctrl-shift-F9 to unlink all the
  relevant field codes, i.e. replace the codes by their results.
- Open the original.
- Copy the figures and their captions from the copy to the original.

However, you would either have to make manual changes to reflect any changes to the numbering sequence after that, or you would have to re-do the whole operation. So it's really a pre-publishing step.

Another option you could consider is to do your references using the rather complicated field coding I have suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682066). The main snag with that (other than its complication and lack of real-world testing) is that as it stands, it may not play well with Word's standard cross-referencing and Tables of Figures features.

Comment: Thanks; I was hoping to retain the dynamic links, so that if I change a figure in the main text, its number updates at the end of the document. Unfortunately scientific journals don't like submissions in formats like LaTeX, which would make this a cinch!

Comment: Yes - I think the second approach would work for you, but as it stands it reequires you to create a name for each figure. I'll try to have a look later, but I suggest you have a look at what's already there - it may even be obvious how it might be modified for your scenario.